# Unable to update the database using the cur.execute?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-connector

I am listening to a port on a python TCP server. I am able to print the received data on the command line. Now, I want to update my database. Since, I am having frequent updates on the database, I am using multi=True. However, I keep getting the error as :

```
cur.execute(query1, multi=True)
```

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Here, is my code below:

```
print "received data:", data
query1= "UPDATE tablename SET col_value = %s where id= %s",(data[0:3], data[4:])

cur.execute(query1,multi=True)
```

> Sample data is: 334,6

Does anyone know, how to resolve this?

Comment: Shouldn't `query1` be something like `query1= "UPDATE tablename SET col_value = %s where id= %s" % (data[0:3], data[4:])`?

Comment: @Fejs: no, this can lead to SQL-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I agree. I wanted to point that maybe syntax used is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), `multi=True` is used to execute multiple SQL statements at once, without parameters. For a single `UPDATE` you can use:

```
print "received data:", data
query1 = "UPDATE tablename SET col_value = %s where id= %s"
cur.execute(query1, (data[0:3], data[4:]))
```

Comment: File "testPythonTCPServer.py", line 34, in clientthread
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 528, in execute
        stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
cur.execute(query1,(data[0:3], data[4:]))
AttributeError  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 528, in execute
:     'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I wanted to use 'multi=True' because earlier I was getting an exception where multiple updates to the database wasn't happening. and, it was suggested in the cmd prompt to use multi=True.

Comment: You seem to still be passing a **tuple** to `execute()` instead of a **string**. Note that there's no comma after the string in my example.